# Instagram in-app browser does not support add to home screen feature for pwa

Tags: android-webview, instagram, progressive-web-apps, beforeinstallprompt

https://caniuse.com/web-app-manifest
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BeforeInstallPromptEvent

Here it says, android webview supports add to home screen. Even then in instagram's in-app browser it doesn't work.

Even the custom install that we trigger using beforeinstallprompt also doesn't show up.

Not any of the documentations mention anything about this.

Answer (score 0):

In IOS there's a way you can install web apps using profile configuration files. Do you know if there is a way to do the same in Android? If so, we can redirect the bio link to an install page of our web apps.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).